# VHDL fixed point implementation of IIR filter

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, fixed-point

I have a filter described by the following transfer function H(z):

$$H(z) = \frac{156 - 156z^{-2}}{16384 - 32443z^{-1}+16073z^{-2}}$$

How will this be implemented with the first term in the polynomium being different from 1?

Normally i would implement the filter with something like:
$$y[0]=156\cdot x[0]-156\cdot x[2] +32443\cdot y[1]-16073\cdot y[2]$$

but in this case, it is missing the term:
$$-16384\cdot y[0]$$

How may this term be inserted? I have tried just inserting it, inserting and shift the y's by 1. I just get noise doing this (looks like overflow).

It is to be implemented in VHDL on a FPGA.

Comment: Hi! I guess you actually want to ask something about **integer** valued coefficients to be used in FPGA arithmetic hardware ?

Comment: Yes, that must be it.

Comment: Then so what's the question about that integer, how to scale it properly ? Please put a lot more hardware and numeric format details.

Comment: I have scaled it by multiplying by 2^14, and bit-shifted 14 times to get my output. If i just send x[0] to myoutput, it is fine. If i add the rest of the differnece exuation, i get noise looking like overflow. 

I am not sure of this is an FPGA implementation problem, or a problem with my difference equation.

Comment: there's a problem withe the LCCDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter output has to be divided by the first term of denominator.
In this case, division by 16384 can be effectively done by logical shift 14 bits to the right.